# Error in RDLC report when a visibility change occurs

Tags: c#, rdlc, .net-4.8

I'm using VS22 and Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022.
My problem is : I have a matrix with data in it and if a visibility change occurs on any of the elements in the page, my lines are filled with "#Error".
Here is a small example I made :

The columns contains the same fields used in the one which doesn't work.

-[Here is a simple title with a hidden textbox underneath and my matrix which is working perfectly fine for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uweue.png)

-[And here is the exact same part with the title opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYb2S.png)

-Here is the value of the last column :

=IIF(Lookup(Fields!DateTime.Value,Fields!DateTime.Value,Fields!StopOnLoad.Value,"dsProduction_dtProdDetailSection") = 1
OR Lookup(Fields!DateTime.Value,Fields!DateTime.Value,Fields!StartOnLoad.Value,"dsProduction_dtProdDetailSection") = 1,
Nothing,
IIF(Fields!Stable.Value = 0, "[", "") & FORMAT(Fields!CurrentFlow.Value, "N2") & iif(Fields!Stable.Value = 0, "]", ""))

I tried using the less possible datas on my report and updating the dll files of Microsoft.ReportViewer in my C# project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.